# How to add a ListView to a Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm trying to construct a simple login page for my Flutter app.  I've successfully built the TextFields and log in/Sign in buttons.  I want to add a horizontal ListView.  When I run the code my elements disappear, if I do it without the ListView, it's fine again. How can I do this correctly?

```dart
return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Login / Signup"),
          ),
          body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "E M A I L    A D D R E S S"
                    ),
                  ),
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
                  new TextField(obscureText: true,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "P A S S W O R D"
                    ),
                    ),
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
                  new TextField(decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "U S E R N A M E"
                  ),),
                  new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
                  child:  new Text("SIGNUP"),),
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
                  new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
                  child: new Text("LOGIN"),),
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
                  new ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
                    child: new Text("Facebook"),),
                    new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.00)),
                    new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
                    child: new Text("Google"),)
                  ],)

                ],
              ),
            ),
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can check console output. It prints error:

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
> The horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
> Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match
> their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of
> vertical space in which to expand.

You need to add a height constraint to your horizontal list. E.g. wrap in [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) with height:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 44.0,
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: <Widget>[
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Text("Facebook"),
      ),
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.00)),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Text("Google"),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: the next two answers give another two solutions and explain what's happening.

Comment: Have any suggest to use dynamic height instead of fix the height of listview?

Answer (score 589):

I've got this problem too. My solution is use `Expanded` widget to expand remain space.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: horizontalList,
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: This is a great solution because it allows for variable sized heights/widths of the ListView, like when you want it to just take up the remaining space.  It allows you to account for varying screen sizes when it's too difficult to know the exact height/width.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This solution allows the ListView to take the rest of the screen without having to deal with media query.

Comment: I'm too new to Flutter to know why this works, but I'm glad it does.  Thank you.
Flutter's error messages weren't very helpful to explain the root cause of this problem for a non-expert.

Comment: simple and what i was looking for .! Would there be any hit on performance and rendering though ?

Comment: Can someone explain what causes this problem and why `Expanded` fixes it?

Answer (score 402):

#### Reason for error:

`Column` expands to the maximum size in main axis direction (vertical axis), and so does the `ListView`.

#### Solutions:

So, you need to constrain the height of the `ListView`. There are many ways of doing it, you can choose that best suits your need.

---

1. If you want to allow `ListView` to take up all remaining space inside `Column`, use `Expanded`.

   ```dart
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded( //        <-- Use Expanded 
         child: ListView(...),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

2. If you want to limit your `ListView` to a certain `height`, use `SizedBox`.

   ```dart
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(
         height: 200, // Constrain height.
         child: ListView(...),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

3. If your `ListView` is small, you may try `shrinkWrap` property on it.

   ```dart
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       ListView(
         shrinkWrap: true, // Set this
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

---

4. If you want to make `ListView` to as small as it can be, use `Flexible` with `ListView.shrinkWrap`:

   ```dart
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Flexible( //        <-- Use Flexible 
         child: ListView(
           shrinkWrap: true, // and set this
         ),
       )
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: your 3rd point is something I highly recommend all beginners to take note of!

Comment: Remember that the listview also can expand with Width, so if your SizedBox isn't working include the Width limit.

Answer (score 48):

Expanded Widget increases its size as much as it can with the space available Since ListView essentially has an infinite height it will cause an error.

```
 Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: ListView(...),
    )
  ],
)
```

Here we should use the `Flexible` widget as it will only take the space it required as Expanded take full screen even if there are not enough widgets to render on full screen.

Answer (score 45):

I have `SingleChildScrollView` as a parent, and one `Column` Widget and then List View Widget as last child.

Adding these properties in List View Worked for me.

```
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
```

Comment: `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical` is the default, so that's not part of the solution. Also, this disables scrolling on the list.

Comment: That has to be an accepted answer! Problem with Expanded and Flexible is `flex`, which takes up all the space which you planned for a different flexible widget. `shrinkWrap` solves that while `physics` disables overflow scrolling effect.

Answer (score 14):

As have been mentioned by others above,Wrap listview with Expanded is the solution.

**But when you deal with nested Columns you will also need to limit your ListView to a certain height (faced this problem a lot).**

If anyone have another solution please, mention in comment or add answer.

*Example*

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Image(image: ),//<< any widgets added
       SizedBox(),
       Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Text('header'),  //<< any widgets added
            Expanded(child: 
            ListView.builder(
              //here your code
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container();
                   } 
         )
        ),
        Divider(),//<< any widgets added
         ],
       ),

     ],
   ), 
  );
```

Comment: in nested columns don't use expanded 
just use shrikWrap: true,  physics: NeverScrolPhysics() properties in listView

Comment: Wrapping the overflowing Column Widget(Check the error message in your terminal you should see the file and line causing the error) with a SingleChildScrollView widget worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Now You could use shrink , sizedbx or flexiable with fit as mention by @CopsOnRoad aboce

Answer (score 11):

Actually, when you read docs the ListView should be inside Expanded Widget so it can work.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      child: PayableWidget(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: _myListView(context),
    )
  ],
));
```

}

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Flex` and `Flexible` widgets. for example:

```
Flex(
direction: Axis.vertical,
children: <Widget>[
    ... other widgets ...
    Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: ...,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            ...
        },
        ),
    ),
],
```

);

Comment: why Flex? can you explain? I think the OP is asking how toadd ListView in a `Column` specifically.

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your Listview with Expanded Widget

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why wrapping the ListView with Expanded solves this?

Comment: This is covered with a _lot_ more detail by several other answers. Please review existing answers before submitting a new one. If you found previous answers useful, upvote them as a way of validating their approach. Please don't repeat answers, unless you have _significantly_ more detail to add.

Answer (score 7):

**You need to do 2 things:**

- wrap `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView`
- add `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in `ListView`

**Why it works:**

As I uderstand, `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` disable scrolling of `ListView`.
So, scroll works with `SingleChildScrollView`.
If I am wrong, comment bellow.

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text('Filter'),
      ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: rides.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          # return some widget
        }
      ),
```

Comment: Clear example and it works perfect.

Answer (score 7):

**[Solution Preview]** - [List Items are scrollable but heading is fixed]

[image]

I have very small & straight forward answer, see putting listview inside column will force column to expand infinitely, which is basically an error thing.

Now if you put `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` like others suggested, in listview then whats the point of having listview if you disable scrolling inside it..

There is an easy fix, frankly I landed on this by hit and trial. Let me give you small explanation after code.

```dart
Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "All Bookings",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.brown[700]),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 30,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("List Item ${index + 1}"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

I had requirement to have title inside Column as first element & then put a Listview so that user can have scrolling list. This is a generic kind of requirement. You can put this in Bottom Sheet or Modal too.

Code Explanation:

1. I kept first child as heading inside Column ok (which i donot want to scroll away, i want it to be fixed)
2. I have Expanded child inside column, which is like acquire all the "remaining space" in column.
3. Inside that I kept container (Just to put some space between title & list view with margin) this is optional, you can remove container and it will still work.
4. Now the Listview is well constrained and it won't try to stretch infinitely in column. As Expanded widget already constrained it.

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere or if this code doesn't work (it works as of now without errors :)

Answer (score 6):

```
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Leading text widget'),
      ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.map),
            title: Text('Map'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
            title: Text('Album'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
            title: Text('Phone'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Text('More widget'),
    ],
  );
```

just use

```
shrinkWrap: true,

physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

properties in listView

Comment: Mind explaining your answer a bit?

Comment: the question is `how to add listview in a column`  I think this solved it for me.  Wonder why this is not voted up.. Maybe im missing something from that popular answer up there?

Comment: I need to wrap `Column` as `child` of `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your list `Flexible`
I hope this help you!

```
 Flexible(
      child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget> [
            Wrap(
              spacing: 12,
              runSpacing: 12,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(5, (index) {
                return MyChip(
                  onChange: (p0) {},
                );
              }),
            )
          ]),
      )
```

Comment: immediate resolution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead, I think you need to use an expanded widget.

```
Column (
  children: <Widget>[
    new TextField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Search something"
    ),
    Expanded(
      ListView(),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can try use `CustomScrollView`

```dart
CustomScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final OrderModel order = _orders[index];

              return Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 8,
                ),
                child: _buildOrderCard(order, size, context),
              );
            },
            childCount: _orders.length,
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: _buildPreloader(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Tip: `_buildPreloader` return `CircularProgressIndicator` or `Text`

In my case i want to show under ListView some widgets. Use `Column` does't work me, because widgets around ListView inside Column showing always "up" on the screen, like "position absolute"

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using

- singleChildScrollView
- Column
- Container
- FutureBuilder
  - Listview

and I wanted to scroll last scroll view with the whole column
for this add

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

this line in your listview.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Nested Column or Have a ListView inside a column and you dont want to scroll your first column items and want to minimize the size of your column and dont wanna use Expanded then my comment is for you.

Example: [image]

What you should do is use `Flex` and `Flexible`.

***Example with Nested column:***
`Use Flex instead of first Column`

```
Flex(
  direction: Axis.vertical,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [

   widgets_that_you_dont_wants_to_scroll(...),
   widgets_that_you_dont_wants_to_scroll(...),

   Flexible(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
            children: [
              ... 
             ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]
    ),
```

***Example for ListView in Column:***
`use Flex instead of first column`

```
Flex(
  direction: Axis.vertical,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [

   widgets_that_you_dont_wants_to_scroll(...),
   widgets_that_you_dont_wants_to_scroll(...),

   Flexible(
     child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 4,
              shrinkWrap: true, // Must add
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                 return ...
              },
           ),
        ),
      ]
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Slivers:

```
Container(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Header 1"),
              HeaderWidget("Header 2"),
              HeaderWidget("Header 3"),
              HeaderWidget("Header 4"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget(Colors.blue),
              BodyWidget(Colors.red),
              BodyWidget(Colors.green),
              BodyWidget(Colors.orange),
              BodyWidget(Colors.blue),
              BodyWidget(Colors.red),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget(Colors.blue),
              BodyWidget(Colors.green),
              BodyWidget(Colors.yellow),
              BodyWidget(Colors.orange),
              BodyWidget(Colors.blue),
              BodyWidget(Colors.red),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Login / Signup"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: ListView(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "E M A I L    A D D R E S S"
                ),
              ),
              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
              new TextField(obscureText: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "P A S S W O R D"
                ),
                ),
              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
              new TextField(decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: "U S E R N A M E"
              ),),
              new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
              child:  new Text("SIGNUP"),),
              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
              new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
              child: new Text("LOGIN"),),
              new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00)),
              new ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
                child: new Text("Facebook"),),
                new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.00)),
                new RaisedButton(onPressed: null,
                child: new Text("Google"),)
              ],)

            ],
          ),
        ),
        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.00),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to rebuild/restart the app as the hot reload did not reflect or apply when I added an `Expanded` around my ListView