# How to add more items in Flutter body

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm learning Flutter and right now I'm calling `_buildStackCardsList` widget in the body but I'm trying to add additional text right above `_buildStackedCardsList` method but I'm not really sure how to implement that. every time I tried to wrap with containers or columns the stackedCard got to disappear.

```
  body: _buildStackedCardsList()
}


  Widget _buildStackedCardsList() {
  }
```

so this is what I trying to do

[image]

any suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutters widget reference is a nice place to start when looking what widgets you can use and how you can implement your layout with it: https://flutter.dev/docs/reference/widgets

Judging from your wireframe I would add a `Column` widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

```
body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Your Text'),
    Expanded(child: _buildStackedCardsList()),
  ],
)
```

Update: Due to size calculation you can not render a `ListView` as a direct child of `Column`. It can be for example wrapped in a `Expanded` widget. The answer to a similar question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132247/4668136

Comment: Hi.. I have tried that and the stackedcards or Text is not showing anymore. I'm not really sure if something wrong with _buildStackedCardList() but if you don't mind can you look into it. I just added the code. thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with a code that should work and a reference question/answer