# Why isn't my ListView.builder showing up?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application that pulls data from Json Dan. I want to pull the data and show it in the carousel. There is no error on the screen and vscode. But my pictures are not visible in the carousel and I get an error like this.

```
           SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 300.0,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.pictures.length - 1,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Carousel(
                            dotSize: 5,
                            dotIncreaseSize: 5,
                            images: [
                              Image.network(snapshot
                                  .data.pictures[index].pictureurl)
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),...
                    ])
```

> E/flutter ( 5060): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
> E/flutter ( 5060): #0      RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:703:26)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #2      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #3      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #4      RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3257:31)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #6      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #8      RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #10     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #12     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #14     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #16     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #18     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:535:18)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #19     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #21     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #23     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #24     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2774:25)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #25     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:786:31)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #26     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2769:33)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #27     RenderFlex.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1072:12)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #28     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #29     _RenderSingleChildViewport.hitTestChildren. (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:661:25)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #30     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:786:31)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #31     _RenderSingleChildViewport.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:656:21)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #32     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #34     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #35     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3257:31)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #37     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #39     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #40     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #41     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #43     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:178:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #45     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #47     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #49     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:535:18)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #50     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #51     RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:131:19)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #52     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #53     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren. (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:92:25)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #54     BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:786:31)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #55     RenderShiftedBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:87:21)
> E/flutter ( 5060): #56     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2413:11)

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView.Builder()` inside an `Expanded` widget. Everytime you have a vertically growing widget e.g. `ListView` or `GridView` insdie a `Column` this error will come. THe fix is either to provide a fixed height or wrap it under a `Expanded` widget.

Check this link for more:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132247/3197387