# Building a UI interface for my flutter project with List view

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying to code the UI for a flutter interface and it was going all well until I added the "ListView" widget. I tried to compile the code and it said that build completed successfully. But when I ran it, the Virtual Android screen loaded a bit, then it turned pitch black. I tried several times but to no avail. Pls can anyone help me with this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Stateful Clicker Counter',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Clicker Counter Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ), //Icon
                  ), //Floatingactionbutton
                ), //Padding
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.pause,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ), //Icon
                  ), //Floatingactionbutton
                ), //Padding
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.mic,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ), //Icon
                  ), //FloatingactionButton
                ), //Padding
                ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.amber[600],
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entry A',
                          ), //Text
                        ), //Center
                    ), //Container
                    Container(
                      height: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.amber[500],
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entry B',
                          ), //Text
                        ), //Center
                    ), //Container
                    Container(
                      height: 30.0,
                      color: Colors.amber[100],
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entry C',
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Container
                  ], //End of Widget tree
                ), //ListView
              ], //End of submain Widget Tree
            ), //Row
          ], //End of Main Widget Tree
        ), //Column
      ), //Main Center
    ); //Scaffold
  }
}
```

P.S: I just started Flutter, so some things might seem unecessary

Comment: Can you add the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Based in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669202/how-to-add-a-listview-to-a-column-in-flutter)

Try adding the `ListView` inside a `Container`

**Updated:**

Now this code should work. The problem is, you added `ListView` inside the `Row` not in `Column`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Stateful Clicker Counter',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Clicker Counter Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key,this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ), //Icon
                  ), //Floatingactionbutton
                ), //Padding
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.pause,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ), //Icon
                  ), //Floatingactionbutton
                ), //Padding
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                    tooltip: 'Increment',
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.mic,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ), //Icon
                  ), //FloatingactionButton
                ), //Padding
              ], //End of submain Widget Tree
            ), //Row
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 10.0,
                      color: Colors.amber[600],
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entry A',
                          ), //Text
                        ), //Center
                    ), //Container
                    Container(
                      height: 10.0,
                      color: Colors.amber[500],
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entry B',
                          ), //Text
                        ), //Center
                    ), //Container
                    Container(
                      height: 10.0,
                      color: Colors.amber[100],
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Entry C',
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Container
                  ], //End of Widget tree
                ), //ListView,
            )
          ], //End of Main Widget Tree
        ),
    ); //Scaffold
  }
}
```

[image]