# Listview.builder not showing my images when implementing in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I am trying to implement a horizontal Listview which shows my images pulled from the Flutter image_picker plugin.

its work fine if I do not use a Listview and only display a single image. however I am trying to use multiple images and as soon as I place within the Listview the widgets just shows up as black. my code for the Listview is as follows:

```
          @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(

  onWillPop: () async {
    
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'inventory');
    return false;
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
      title: Text(
        'MyApp',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      leading: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
              context,
              'inventory');
        },
      ),

      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
          child: Container(

            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white, //remove this when you add image.
            ),

            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context,'profile');

              },
              child: Image(
                image:NetworkImage("imageUrl goes here"),
                width: 120,
                height: 120,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,

              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],

    ),
    body: SafeArea(

      child: Column(

        children: [

          pickedFile == null ?
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {

              _showMyDialog();

              setState(() {


              });
            },

            child: Container(

              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Click to add a Photo',textAlign: 
TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Icon(

                    Icons.add_circle_outline,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                    size: 30,

                  ),

                ],
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(

                  border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.grey),

                  shape: BoxShape.circle
              ),

            ),
          )
              :
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {

                _showMyDialog();

                setState(() {


                });
              },


              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: _imageFileList!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                   
 return kIsWeb

                        ? Image.network(_imageFileList![index].path)
                        : Image.file(File(_imageFileList! 
  [index].path));

                  }
              )

  ],
      ),

  ),),
  );
  }
}
```

I am not showing the whole code as the page is too long however the rest of the page works fine. if i remove the Listview builder and instead test using just the below it works fine. what am i doing wrong?

```
            child: Row(
              children: [
                        kIsWeb
                          ? Container(
                          child: Image.network(_imageFileList![index].path))
                          : Container(
                          child: Image.file(File(_imageFileList![index].path)));

                    }
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Please help.

**Edited the above code with my full widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue. it was related to a height constraint which needed to be added. found the solution in this link

[How to add a ListView to a Column in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669202/how-to-add-a-listview-to-a-column-in-flutter/45670718#45670718)

Answer (score 1):

Either use `Row` or use `ListView`, not both.

You can use Row with `List.generate`:

```dart
Row(
  children: List.generate(_imageFileList!.length, 
    (i) => kIsWeb
         ? Container(child: Image.network(_imageFileList![index].path))
         : Container(child: Image.file(File(_imageFileList![index].path))
),
```

Or `ListView` exactly how you have it without the `Row`. `ListView` is probably the widget you’re wanting to use. `Row` will overflow if the content is larger than the width while `ListView` will act as its own ScrollView in that situation.

I’d also double-check that you need that `Expanded` widget. That’s typically for use *inside* a Row (or similar widgets).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and removed both the expanded and row and the listview still comes back black. i have updated my question to include the full scaffold and removed the unnecessary bits.

Comment: Managed to find the issue. it was a height issue. i had to add a container around the Listview.builder. Found it in another article. will paste a link to the comment below.