# How to add a ListView to a Column?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I want to add my `ListView.seperated` into Column, so that I can add CircularProgressIndicator below this ListvView when loading more items. I have used advices from [How to add a ListView to a Column in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669202/how-to-add-a-listview-to-a-column-in-flutter) so that I made structure Column -> Expanded -> ListVie, but I got errors and list cannot be loaded:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e8fad NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1929 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C://lib/ui/pages/home/page/HomePage.dart:125:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderFlex.performLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:926:9)
#1      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:929:6)
#2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1781:7)
#3      ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:54:11)
#4      RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)

  Column file:///C:/.../.../lib/ui/pages/home/page/HomePage.dart:125:16
```

Could you tell me what have I done wrong? This `AdvertisementTile` builds new widgets, but it is built onto another column. Maybe this is wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:.../ui/pages/home/page/AdvertisementCard.dart';
import 'package:.../ui/pages/home/page/model/AdvertisementList.dart';

import '../../SizedBox.dart';
import 'AdvertisementProdRepository.dart';
import 'BottomAppBar.dart';
import 'FAB.dart';
import 'model/AdvertisementList.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String jwt;

  const HomePage(this.jwt);

  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();

  factory HomePage.fromBase64(String jwt) => HomePage(jwt);
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  late final String jwt;
  late Future<AdvertisementList> _listOfItems;
  final searchTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    jwt = widget.jwt;
    _listOfItems = AdvertisementProdRepository.fetchAdvertisements(1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFEF9F9FC),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: buildFAB(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BuildBottomAppBar(),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25, top: 25),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: searchTextController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Szukaj',
                      fillColor: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                      filled: true),
                ),
                buildSizedBox(20.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Najnowsze ogłoszenia',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                buildSizedBox(10.0),
                FutureBuilder<AdvertisementList>(
                  future: _listOfItems,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    } else {
                      return AdvertisementTile(advertisements: snapshot.data!);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class AdvertisementTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final AdvertisementList advertisements;

  AdvertisementTile({Key? key, required this.advertisements}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AdvertisementTileState();
}

class AdvertisementTileState extends State<AdvertisementTile> {
  AdvertisementLoadMoreStatus loadMoreStatus =
      AdvertisementLoadMoreStatus.STABLE;
  final ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
  late List<Advertisement> advertisements;
  late int currentPageNumber;
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    advertisements = widget.advertisements.items;
    currentPageNumber = widget.advertisements.pageNumber;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener(
      onNotification: onNotification,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: advertisements.length,
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return AdvertisementCard(data: advertisements[index]);
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
  /*child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 28.0),*/
  bool onNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent > scrollController.offset &&
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - scrollController.offset <=
              50) {
        if (loadMoreStatus == AdvertisementLoadMoreStatus.STABLE) {
          loadMoreStatus = AdvertisementLoadMoreStatus.LOADING;
          _loading = true;
          AdvertisementProdRepository.fetchAdvertisements(currentPageNumber + 1)
              .then((advertisementObject) {
            currentPageNumber = advertisementObject.pageNumber;
            loadMoreStatus = AdvertisementLoadMoreStatus.STABLE;
            setState(() => advertisements.addAll(advertisementObject.items));
            _loading = false;
          });
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}

enum AdvertisementLoadMoreStatus { LOADING, STABLE }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should constrain the height of the `Listview` as the `Column` wants to get all the available height of its parent (likely `Scaffold` in your case). So, an unbounded-height-widget as a `Listview` will cause this kind of error.
Solution: wrap the `Listview` with a `Container` of some height.

Comment: yea, but how can I know the height of the container if list can return 10 or 20 elements? Im not sure how much items will be returned. Also I dont know resoltuion of user phone so it should be dynamically.

Comment: to calculate the height dynamically you can set the `Container` height as follows `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6`.
and you can set `shrinkWrap` proberty of the `Listview` to `true` so that the `Listview` will wrap its content and be as high as its children allows it to be.

Comment: now the issue is you don't know how many items will be retrieved
so you can have a variable `bool smallNumofItems` and a have a condition on the `Container` height to be null if `smallNumofItems` is true otherwise use `MediaQuery`
with `shrinkWrap` set to true as it is.

Comment: but why with Expanded it does not work? It is one of solutions in link I provided in question.

Comment: Wrapping the `Listview` with `Expanded` is like expanding what is already expanded.  that's why the CircularProgressIndicator() won't appear.
by the way there is a package that achieve this, it's called [lazy loading](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview)

Answer (score 1):

So the way a `Column` behaves is that when you give it 2 *children*, the flutter engine estimates the space that the single widget would cover, and then it would render those two widgets accordingly.
An `Expanded` widget tells flutter to take a widget and then cover as much space as that widget can take. In some cases, it makes sense to use an `Expanded` widget if the other widget is wrapped in a `Container`, this way flutter knows that you are referring to the remaining space.
`ListView` is a widget that takes all available spaces available.

So to fix your render issue you can put the `Listview` in a `Container` and give the `Container` a fixed *height* then flutter knows how to manage your screen and avoid the rendering issue.

If you eventually get any, you'll still have most of your UI, then you'll just have to tweak the *height* of your `Container`.

E.g

```
                      Container(
                        height: 400,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return AdvertisementCard(
                                  data: advertisements[index]);
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              );
                            },
                            itemCount: reports.length),
                      )
```

Comment: yea, but how can I know the height of the container if list can return 10 or 20 elements? Im not sure how much items will be returned. Also I dont know resoltuion of user phone so it should be dynamically.