# Flutter: RenderFlex overflow when using column

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow, flutter-renderflex-error

I'm getting a renderflex overflow error which displays as the following: [image: overflow]

It's coming from the following code:

```
                  return Column(
                      children: [
                        DropdownButton<String>(
                            items: Utils.ddsDropdown
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {}),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16, 0, 16),
                          itemCount: card.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return MyCard.buildCard(card[index], context);
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    )
```

I also tried to wrap the column in an `Expanded` widget and in a `SingleChildScrollView` but still got the same error. I think the column is preventing the page from being fully scrollable. But I need the column to be able to have the DropdownButton and ListView.

I even tried wrapping the entire widget in a `SingleChildScrollView` as follows:

```
        Widget build(BuildContext context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: MyCard.getData(widget.categoryIndex, widget.subCategories)!
            .whenComplete(() => setState(() {
                  isLoading = false;
                })),
        builder: ((context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
            return FutureBuilder<List<MyCard>>(
                future: MyCard.readData(snapshot.data),
                builder: (context, cards) {
                  if (cards.hasData) {
                    final card = cards.data!;
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        //Text("Hello"),
                        DropdownButton<String>(
                            items: Utils.ddsDropdown
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                            onChanged: (value) {}),
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16, 0, 16),
                          itemCount: card.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return MyCard.buildCard(card[index], context);
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Text("No data");
                  }
                });
          } else {
            return isLoading
                ? Column(
                    children: const [CircularProgressIndicator()],
                  )
                : const Text("You do not have any workouts yet");
          }
        }),
      ));
```

but it still overflows.

Comment: can you include more about parent widget

Comment: The issue was the parent widget. The parent widget was a `Column`, so I changed it to `Center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap only the ListView in Expanded as follows:

```
Column(
  children: [
    DropdownButton<String>(
    ...
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
...
```

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132247/7432242) will provide you with further details about your question.

Comment: I tried that and got an error saying that: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: Solved, the problem is that I was wrapping this widget in a Column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` to use a scrollable area of that column as below:

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
                  children: [
                    DropdownButton<String>(
                        items: Utils.ddsDropdown
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (value) {}),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 16, 0, 16),
                      itemCount: card.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return MyCard.buildCard(card[index], context);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                )
```

I hope this solved your problem.

Comment: I tried it but I am still getting a RenderFlex overflow error